# Tomcat Clustering With Apache-[warn] proxy: No protocol handler was valid for the URL /. If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat, cluster, mod-proxy, proxypass

I am new to apache and tomcat, and trying to implement clustering with mod_proxy and able get run multiple tomcat instances but got stuck. Here is my config:

```
httpd.conf:

LoadModule proxy_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_proxy_http.so
LoadModule proxy_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_proxy_balancer.so
<Proxy balancer://testcluster stickysession=JSESSIONID>
BalancerMember ajp://localhost:8109 min=10 max=100 route=server1 loadfactor=1
BalancerMember ajp://localhost:8209 min=20 max=200 route=server2 loadfactor=1
</Proxy>
ProxyPass / balancer://testcluster/
```

When restarting apache its showing the following in error.log:

```
[Fri Feb 27 16:45:44 2015] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Feb 27 16:46:48 2015] [warn] proxy: No protocol handler was valid for the URL /. If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.
```

And also my server.xml of two instances has set to jvmRoute="server1" and jvmRoute="server1"....

Comment: Did you enable required Apache modules ? `a2enmod proxy` `a2enmod proxy_http` ?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but maybe the answer is helpful to others.

The module names of the last two loaded modules are wrong. `mod_proxy_ajp.so` is loaded as `proxy_module` and `mod_proxy_balancer.so` as `proxy_http_module`.

**wrong:**

```
LoadModule proxy_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_proxy_balancer.so
```

**right:**

```
LoadModule proxy_ajp_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so
LoadModule proxy_balancer_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_proxy_balancer.so
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which OS you are using but it is customary to do the following:

1. Enable the modules: `a2enmod proxy` `a2enmod proxy_http`.
2. In your case, you want to use AJP so you probably have to install a thing or two (e.g. `a2enmod proxy_ajp`).
3. In your Virtual Host (you can do `http.conf` but it's not the most flexible way).

This is what you have copied from your question:

```
<Proxy balancer://testcluster stickysession=JSESSIONID>
  BalancerMember ajp://localhost:8109 min=10 max=100 route=server1 loadfactor=1
  BalancerMember ajp://localhost:8209 min=20 max=200 route=server2 loadfactor=1
<Proxy>
ProxyPass / balancer://testcluster/
```

This is how I do it (not much different):

```
<Proxy balancer://testcluster >
  BalancerMember ajp://localhost:8109 min=10 max=100 route=server1 loadfactor=1
  BalancerMember ajp://localhost:8209 min=20 max=200 route=server2 loadfactor=1
<Proxy>
ProxyPass / balancer://testcluster/ stickysession=JSESSIONID
```